# Error while adding new product in existing product list in AngularJS service

Tags: angularjs

I have a service that fetches the products from the DB (only once) and is able to add new product to DB.

```
sampleApp.factory('ProductService', function($http) {

var promise;
var ProductService =  {};

ProductService.GetProducts = function() {
    var req = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: ProductURL,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        //data: "action=GET"
    };
    if ( !promise ) {
            promise = $http(req).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            return response.data;
        });
    }
    return promise;
}

ProductService.AddNewProduct = function(NewProduct)  {

    var ProductData = {};
    ProductData = NewProduct;
    ProductData = JSON.stringify(ProductData);
    alert (ProductData);
    promise.push(NewProduct)    // this line giving error

    var req = {
        url: "cgi-bin/AddNewProduct.pl",
        method: 'GET',
        params: {ProductID: NewProduct.ProductID, ProductName: NewProduct.ProductName, ProductImagePath: NewProduct.ProductImagePath, BrandID: NewProduct.BrandID, SubCategoryID: NewProduct.SubCategoryID}
        //params: { NewProduct: ProductData }
    };

    $http(req).success(function()
    {
        alert ('New Product Added!');
    })
    .error(function()
    {
        alert ('New Product Add Error!');
    });
}

return ProductService;
});
```

While adding a new product in DB, i want this new product to get added in existing products list also.

But this line giving me a error:

```
promise.push(NewProduct)    // this line giving error
```

TypeError: promise.push is not a function

How to fix this error? Is there any better way to achieve the same.

Comment: you have to initialize promise with `var promise = [];` , if you want to use it like an array.

Comment: Promise looks like a var to me (not an array) try making it an array,

Comment: @obrejacatalin Then i think i can not use if ( !promise ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focusing on this bit of code:

```
if ( !promise )
{
   promise = $http(req).then(function (response) {
     console.log(response);
     return response.data;
   });
}
return promise;
```

First you need to realize that `$http(req).then(...)` will return a promise and the return value from inside the first `then` will just be passed to the next function in the chain of promises. What you need to do instead is assign the result of the `$http` call to some internal variable of your service:

```
if ( !productList )
{
   return $http(req).then(function (response) {
     productList = response.data
     return response.data;
   });
}
else 
{
   return productList;
}
```

Now this still has a problem, because it will return a promise in one instance and an array in the other, so you need to make it always return a promise:

```
sampleApp.factory('ProductService', function($http, $q) {

  ...


if ( !productList )
{
   return $http(req).then(function (response) {
     productList = response.data
     return response.data;
   });
}
else 
{
   var deferred = $q.defer();
   deferred.resolve(productList);
   return deferred.promise;
}
```

Then you should change your AddNew method to add to the `productList` variable. Please check first if it is an array.

---

#### Note 1:

It's a bit weird to retrieve a list of products with a POST and add a new product with a GET (shouldn't you be doing it the other way around?)

#### Note 2

Angular has a mechanism to cache requests using `$cacheFactory` and there are some other libraries available if you don't want to use cacheFactory, like: https://github.com/jmdobry/angular-cache